# Custom featured image as header on blog page

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

I have created a page called **News**, which I'm using as the **Blog Page**. I have inserted an image as featured image in the header **(set as background image)**, but what is displayed there is the featured image of the very **last** blog post. How can I force WordPress to use the featured image of that **specific page** instead of a **Thumbnail** from the **blog post**?

To be more specific, here is my code (in header.php):

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
        $image = $image[0]; ?>
        <?php else :
        $image = get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory') . '/images/fullscreen.jpg'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <header style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')" > ... </div>
```

Comment: Share the code you've tried

Comment: you should check for background image , how does it sets ? via css or `<img>` try to figure first how does it being display, after that you can use get the featured image of specific page using hardcode page id or slug, also you can show image in header by using `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ` it will print html with `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

You need to define the page ID outside the loop.

```
$page_id = get_query_var('page_id');

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $page_id ) ) : ?>

<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_id ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );

<header style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')" > ... </div>

<?php endif ; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the code to my question. How would I need to adjust it?

Comment: Thank you. But couldn't make it work...  This code is in my index.php, header.php still like above.
`<?php $page_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
       <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $page->ID ) ): ?>
       <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
       <?php endif ?>`

Comment: I've edited the code again, I missed that you had the code in header.php :)

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code on header.

```
if(is_page('YOUR BLOG PAGE NAME')){

   Put your header background code......

 }
```

You can also add different page with different images on header with.

```
 if(is_page('PAGE 1 NAME')){

   Put your header background code......

 }elseif(is_page('PAGE 2 NAME'))
```